# How to apply sed to a grep result in a bash script?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to modify a csv file with some sed commands but only on the rows that match certain regex.

I have a grep command that works fine in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash   
   
egrep  '^[A-Z][a-z]*,2018' happiness.csv
```

And the desired sed commands that work correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash   
       
sed  -re '

 s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g
 s/[a-z]/\U&/g
 s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/\1/g
  
' happiness.csv
```

When I combine them together in one script the grep command gets omitted and the script runs only the sed commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash   
   
egrep  '^[A-Z][a-z]*,2018' happiness.csv

sed  -re '

 s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g
 s/[a-z]/\U&/g
 s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/\1/g
  
' happiness.csv
```

Sample data:

```
Country name,Year,Life Ladder,Log GDP per capita,Social support,Healthy life expectancy at birth,Freedom to make life choices,Generosity,Perceptions of corruption,Positive affect,Negative affect,Confidence in national government,Democratic Quality,Delivery Quality,Standard deviation of ladder by country-year,Standard deviation/Mean of ladder by country-year,GINI index (World Bank estimate),"GINI index (World Bank estimate), average 2000-16","gini of household income reported in Gallup, by wp5-year","Most people can be trusted, Gallup","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 1981-1984","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 1989-1993","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 1994-1998","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 1999-2004","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 2005-2009","Most people can be trusted, WVS round 2010-2014"
Afghanistan,2008,3.723589897,7.168690205,0.450662315,50.79999924,0.718114316,0.177888572,0.88168633,0.517637193,0.25819549,0.61207211,-1.929689646,-1.655084372,1.774661899,0.476599723,,,,,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2009,4.401778221,7.333789825,0.55230844,51.20000076,0.678896368,0.200178429,0.850035429,0.583925605,0.23709242,0.611545205,-2.044092655,-1.635024786,1.722687602,0.391361743,,,0.441905767,0.286315262,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2018,4.75838089,7.386628628,0.539075196,51.59999847,0.60012722,0.13435255,0.706766069,0.61826545,0.275323808,0.299357414,-1.991810083,-1.617176056,1.878621817,0.394802749,,,0.327318162,0.275832713,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2011,3.83171916,7.415018559,0.521103561,51.91999817,0.495901406,0.172136664,0.731108546,0.611387312,0.267174691,0.307385713,-1.919018269,-1.616221189,1.78535974,0.465942234,,,0.336764246,,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2012,3.782937527,7.517126083,0.520636737,52.24000168,0.530935049,0.244272724,0.775619805,0.710384727,0.267919123,0.435440153,-1.842995763,-1.40407753,1.798283219,0.47536689,,,0.344539613,,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2013,3.572100401,7.522237778,0.48355186,52.56000137,0.577955365,0.070402659,0.8232041,0.620584846,0.273328096,0.482847273,-1.879708767,-1.403035522,1.223689914,0.342568725,,,0.304368466,,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2014,3.130895615,7.516955376,0.525568426,52.88000107,0.508514047,0.113184482,0.871241987,0.531691492,0.374860734,0.409047514,-1.773256779,-1.312502503,1.395396113,0.445685923,,,0.413973927,,,,,,,
Afghanistan,2015,3.982854605,7.500538826,0.528597236,53.20000076,0.388927579,0.089090675,0.880638301,0.553553164,0.339276046,0.260557145,-1.84436357,-1.29159379,2.16061759,0.542479634,,,0.59691757,,,,,,,
Albania,2018,4.220168591,7.497038364,0.559071779,53,0.522566199,0.051364917,0.793245554,0.564952672,0.348332286,0.324989557,-1.855426311,-1.392712831,1.796219468,0.42562741,,,0.418629497,,,,,,,
```

Desired output:

```
COUNTRY NAME,YEAR,LIFE LADDER,LOG GDP PER CAPITA,SOCIAL SUPPORT,HEALTHY LIFE EXPECTANCY AT BIRTH,FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES,GENEROSITY,PERCEPTIONS OF CORRUPTION,POSITIVE AFFECT,NEGATIVE AFFECT,CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT,DEMOCRATIC QUALITY,DELIVERY QUALITY,STANDARD DEVIATION OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,STANDARD DEVIATION/MEAN OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE),"GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE), AVERAGE 2000-16","GINI OF HOUSEHOLD INCOME REPORTED IN GALLUP, BY WP5-YEAR","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, GALLUP","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1981-1984","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1989-1993","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1994-1998","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1999-2004","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 2005-2009","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 2010-2014" 

AFGHANISTAN,2018,2.69,7.49,-0.50,52.59,0.37,-0.08,0.92,0.42,0.40,0.36,NULL,NULL,1.40,0.52,NULL,NULL,0.29,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
ALBANIA,2018,4.63,9.07,-0.82,65.80,0.52,-0.01,0.87,0.55,0.24,0.30,-0.04,-0.42,1.76,0.38,NULL,0.30,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.24,0.23,NULL,       ARGENTINA,2018,5.48,9.16,-0.83,66.19,0.52,-0.16,0.86,0.64,0.27,NULL,0.04,-0.26,1.91,0.34,NULL,0.30,0.61,0.11,NULL,NULL,0.24,0.23,NULL,
```

Comment: You need a real CSV parser for that [like this](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) since your field values have commas.

Comment: Your desired output is not consistent with the sample data. The line `Afghanistan,2018,4.75838089,`... cannot be transformed to `AFGHANISTAN,2018,2.69,`... by your `sed` command. How is it possible to convert `4.75838089` to `2.69` ?

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:awk] if your question title is only about [tag:sed] and [tag:grep]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a bash pro but this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash   

grep_res=$(egrep  '^[Aa]+.*,2018' happiness.csv)

echo "$grep_res" | sed  -re '
s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g
s/[a-z]/\U&/g
s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/\1/g
'
```

What it does is it saves output of the grep at `grep_res` variable and than feeds sed command with it.

Comment: Running 2 commands will be less efficient than a single `sed`. For running `grep + sed` use: `grep -E '^[Aa]+.*,2018' happiness.csv | sed '...'`

Answer (score 5):

You can search using same regex that you have in `egrep` and make sure to group all substitution commands:

```sh
sed -nE '1p; /^[A-Z][a-z]*,2018/ {
s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g; s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1NULL\2/g
s/[a-z]+/\U&/g
s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+/\1/gp
}' happiness.csv

AFGHANISTAN,2018,4.75,7.38,0.53,51.59,0.60,0.13,0.70,0.61,0.27,0.29,-1.99,-1.61,1.87,0.39,NULL,NULL,0.32,0.27,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
ALBANIA,2018,4.22,7.49,0.55,53,0.52,0.05,0.79,0.56,0.34,0.32,-1.85,-1.39,1.79,0.42,NULL,NULL,0.41,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava, unfortunately, it did not work. The output of the script is exactly the same as the original file.

Comment: It is because in your sample input there is no line that matches `^[A-Z][a-z]*,2018` pattern

Comment: I have modified that! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! It works correctly, taking into account that my original regex was incorrect as it does not take into account the header. Nevertheless, I would still want to understand how to combine grep and sed in one script, if that is possible.

Comment: By using `/^[A-Z][a-z]*,2018/` we are making `sed` search files with this pattern and running all `s/.../.../` commands on matched lines only. Note that we have `-n` in `sed` to suppress normal output and use `p` later to print substituted lines.

Comment: @KlauRau You can't combine them in the way you're thinking of. `grep` allows you to make a file (or pipe) containing *copies of* selected lines in the original file, but there's no good way to make changes to those copies also happen to the original lines (in the original file) as well.

Comment: @KlauRau: I have take care of printing first header line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution with standard Linux `awk` (gawk) script.

Includes dealing with first line.

#### script.awk

```
{ $0 = toupper($0);}   #Upper case each incoming line
/^[A-Z]*,2018/ || NR == 1 {    # deal with first line or matching with /^[A-Z]*,2018/
  $0 = gensub(/([,])([,]|$)/, "\\1NULL\\2", "g", $0); # replace ,, with ,NULL,
  $0 = gensub(/([,])([,]|$)/, "\\1NULL\\2", "g", $0); # replace remaining ,, with ,NULL,
  $0 = gensub(/([0-9]+.[0-9])([0-9])([0-9])*/, "\\1\\2", "g", $0); # trim decimal point numbers
  print $0; # print output line
}
```

#### running

```
 awk -f script.awk happiness.csv
```

#### output

```
$ awk -f script.awk input.csv
COUNTRY NAME,YEAR,LIFE LADDER,LOG GDP PER CAPITA,SOCIAL SUPPORT,HEALTHY LIFE EXPECTANCY AT BIRTH,FREEDOM TO MAKE LIFE CHOICES,GENEROSITY,PERCEPTIONS OF CORRUPTION,POSITIVE AFFECT,NEGATIVE AFFECT,CONFIDENCE IN NATIONAL GOVERNMENT,DEMOCRATIC QUALITY,DELIVERY QUALITY,STANDARD DEVIATION OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,STANDARD DEVIATION/MEAN OF LADDER BY COUNTRY-YEAR,GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE),"GINI INDEX (WORLD BANK ESTIMATE), AVERAGE 2000-16","GINI OF HOUSEHOLD INCOME REPORTED IN GALLUP, BY WP5-YEAR","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, GALLUP","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1981-19","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1989-19","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, 
WVS ROUND 1994-19","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 1999-20","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 2005-20","MOST PEOPLE CAN BE TRUSTED, WVS ROUND 2010-20"
AFGHANISTAN,2018,4.75,7.38,0.53,51.59,0.60,0.13,0.70,0.61,0.27,0.29,-1.99,-1.61,1.87,0.39,NULL,NULL,0.32,0.27,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
ALBANIA,2018,4.22,7.49,0.55,53,0.52,0.05,0.79,0.56,0.34,0.32,-1.85,-1.39,1.79,0.42,NULL,NULL,0.41,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```